# Random Content Array seems stuck

Tags: php, arrays, random

I have a random content script that has worked perfectly but now seems to have a glitch.

It's the "Spotlight On:" story on the upper lefthand corner at http://fiction.deslea.com/index2.php and the code is as follows:

```
$storyspotlights = array("bluevial", "biophilia", "real", "edgeofreality", 
"limitsofperception", "markofcain", "spokenfor", "closer", 
"feildelm", "purgatory", "elemental");

$randomstoryID = array_rand($storyspotlights);

$randomstory = $storyspotlights[$randomstoryID];

switch ($randomstory) {

    case ($randomstory == 'closer'):

        $storyspotlightheader = "<div class='storyspotlightheader'>Closer</div>";
        $storyspotlighttext = "snip";

//some stories snipped

    case ($randomstory == 'bluevial'):

        $storyspotlightheader = "<div class='storyspotlightheader'>The Blue
                                Vial</div>";
        $storyspotlighttext = "snip";

    break;

//more stories snipped

    }

print($storyspotlightheader);
print($storyspotlighttext);
```

My problem is - all the stories from Blue Vial to Spoken For appear when you refresh the page, in random order (although Blue Vial seems to stick a fair bit). These were the stories in the script originally.

Since then I have added the last four to the array and the content generation switch case fragment, but these last four stories never, ever appear in the randomiser. I've literally sat and refreshed for hours. I've confirmed over and over that the updated script is on the server, and even deleted and re-uploaded it.

I did try unset and also $storyspotlights = array() at the beginning of the script at various stages of troubleshooting, but to no avail. I also tried moving the new stories to the start of the array - no change there either.

What am I missing?

Comment: What is your **exact** question?

Comment: This works only if you have 2 values in your array, since your cases are solved into TRUE/FALSE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's surprising this works at all. That's not how you use `switch..case`.

```
switch (<value to compare>) {

    case <value to compare against>:
        ...

}
```

That means you write this:

```
switch ($randomstory) {

    case 'closer':
        ...

}
```

With what you've written it's actually executing like:

```
if ($randomstory == ($randomstory == 'closer')) ...
```

Also make sure you have not actually forgotten some `break` statements, which would make the code fall through to the next case and indeed make certain cases "more sticky" than others.

Also, I'd simplify the whole thing to this:

```
$stories = array(
    array('header' => '...', 'text' => '...'),
    array('header' => '...', 'text' => '...'),
    ...
);

$story = $stories[array_rand($stories)];

echo $story['header'];
echo $story['text'];
```

Comment: Thanks deceze, it was indeed a case of missing "break". Just goes to show how you can look at a thing a thousand times and miss something staring you in the face. Thanks for the tips on streamlining, too - this fragment has probably been recycled through half a dozen websites down the years, and since it works, I've not actually looked at whether it was efficient at what it does.